# What are the available method that can alleviate the overfitting problem in traditional OLS problem, but still can get a linear fitting?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear, overfitting, ridge-regression

Recently, I have read the paper https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56def54a45bf21f27e160072/t/5a0d0673419202ef1b2259f2/1510803060244/The_Sampling_Error_in_Estimates_of_Mean-Variance_Efficient_Portfolio_Weights.pdf.

The gist of the paper is that the traditional mean-variance portfolio can be viewed as the OLS solution, where the poor-performance of the traditinal mean-variance portfolio is attributable to the various problems of OLS ( such as overtting.).

Now I'm searching some regression methods that can alleviate the overfitting problem, but still can give some 'linear' fitting solution. I have seen Lasso, Ridge, PCA Regression, and Partial Least Sqaure approach. Methods such as Decision tree or Artifical Neural network does not seem to match my interest since it does not provide explicit linear relations btw dependent and independent variable.

Can someone can recommend some recent (or traditional but not cited above) techniques arising from the motivation to alleviate the overfitting problem of OLS but still retains the linear relationships of the variables?

Thank you.